# Many to Many between multiple Tables

Tags: database, many-to-many, relational-database

I'm dealing with a scenario where users can be associated with specific products in distinct roles. This implies that UserA can be involved with ProductB in the capacity of RoleC, and likewise, UserA might also be linked to ProductC in the role of RoleD, and so on.

To manage this, I've set up a junction table with fields for userId, roleId, and productId.

However, I'm finding the querying process to be quite intricate. Do you have any suggestions for a more efficient solution?

I've also had difficulty finding examples online that explain this type of relationship, which leads me to believe that I might be missing something or possibly doing something incorrectly. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I attempted to set up a junction table in my database to manage the relationships between users, products, and roles. I expected this approach to work smoothly, but I'm facing challenges in querying and managing the data effectively. I'm seeking advice on whether there might be a more efficient way to handle this type of many-to-many relationship. Additionally, I've been struggling to find comprehensive examples online, which has led me to question if I may be overlooking something in my implementation. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "*I'm finding the querying process to be quite intricate.*" How?  Your question is far too vague. There are a total of 4 tables (3 source tables and 1 junction) with join conditions that should be self-explanatory. That isn't overly complex. Try making you question more specific. Include any query that you have tried in the question, if there are problems with it then we can help with that.